# Carto isochrones funtion returns syntax error

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto, isochrone

Using this snippet of code:

```
INSERT INTO my_new_table 
    (the_geom) SELECT (cdb_isodistance(the_geom, 'walk', 
    string_to_array(distance, ',')::integer[])).the_geom 
FROM my_original_pts_table
```

I am trying to create isochrones for a table of points.  I get an error after applying an `INSERT`.

Why is the first geom in parenthesis? Is the distance parameter something that will vary from table to table? After this does work, I still have to wrap it in a `ST_Transform` correct?

Comment: There are really too many questions here for a focussed answer. First of all, what does the error say? The reason it is in parenthesis is because cdb_isodistance presumably is a set returning function and so the (....).the_geom bit means just return the geometry -- ST_Dump works the same way, if you want to understand this better.

Comment: The error I get is `Syntax error: relation "my_new_table" does not exist` It doesn't exist because I am in the process of creating, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `the_geom` is in parenthesis because it [is the proper way to do an `INSERT` in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html). Secondly, the distance parameter is up to the user. You can use a fixed value from a dataset column or something like this if you want just one track:

```
SELECT (cdb_isodistance(cdb_latlng(41,-3), 'walk', ARRAY[300]::integer[])).the_geom
```

Or more than one (i.e. three):

```
SELECT (cdb_isodistance(cdb_latlng(41,-3), 'walk', ARRAY[300,600,900]::integer[])).the_geom
```

And this is the result if you wrap the first query with `ST_AsText`:

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((-2.99880970689654 40.9988826465517,-2.998809 40.998883,-2.997996 40.999345,-2.997987 40.999354,-2.998112 40.999221,-2.99828 40.999043,-2.99880970689654 40.9988826465517)),((-3.00064100000013 40.9983293333333,-3.000817 40.998276,-3.00063 40.998333,-3.00064100000013 40.9983293333333)),((-2.99880970689654 40.9988826465517,-2.998811 40.998882,-2.998848 40.998871,-3.00066 40.998323,-3.00064100000013 40.9983293333333,-3.00052 40.998366,-2.999707 40.998612,-2.998868 40.998865,-2.99880970689654 40.9988826465517)))
```

And finally, don't need to use `ST_Transform`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The error I get is `Syntax error: relation "my_new_table" does not exist`

Comment: So, you need to create a new (empty) dataset named "my_new_table".